# postgresql limit the number of foreign key available for a given table

Tags: postgresql

Here the situation, I am setting up a database using postgresql. In my database I have a league and a number of team associated with the league how can I set a minimum number of team that can be associated with a particular league ?

Comment: It's unlikely you can specify the minimum for that.

Comment: Even if you can make that a database constraint (each league must have N teams), how would you then add teams to a new league, assuming N is greater than 1?  Database constraints like this can make life difficult in many unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with triggers. When a team is added (`INSERT`ed), removed (`DELETE`d) or `UPDATE`d to change teams, a `BEFORE` trigger should `SELECT 1 FROM league WHERE league_id = NEW.team_id FOR UPDATE` to lock the associated league row for the new and/or old team, depending on the type of change.

Then an `AFTER` trigger does a `COUNT` query for the old and/or new leagues to check that the constraint is satisfied and `RAISE`s an exception if it isn't.

You'd need a field to mark a league "active" or "inactive" where the constraint is only checked when it's active, otherwise you'd never be able to create the first few teams.

Answer (score 0):

You would not set this up as a constraint.  Instead, you could set this up as a flag at the `league` level.  The flag would specify if there are enough teams for the league to be active.

One way to maintain the flag is to use a trigger to update the value every time a team is inserted, deleted, or updated in a way that changes the league.